# Windows embedded 8 development

Tags: windows-8, embedded

I am new to the embedded series of Windows and have some questions.

First of all, which is the most used programming language in use for application development on Windows embedded systems: C++ or C#?

I want to develop a simple application on [Windows Embedded 8 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded#Windows_Embedded_Standard), to show the capability of the GUI elements. Which framework is used for the development and what are the development tools?

I'm not really interested in the creating an image topic, more in the how to create applications running on Windows Embedded 8 systems.

Comment: C# and WPF will give you access to the latest capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons for using Windows Embedded is exactly in order that you can use any language supported by Windows itself.  Since the platform itself imposes few if any restrictions, the most suitable language will be largely dependent on the nature of your application, and perhaps the experience of your staff.

C# is the path-of-least resistance with respect to using the .NET framework, while C++ and C++/CLI support greater performance in most cases, but those are not the only options.

In embedded systems in general C and C++ are prevalent but that is largely due to size, performance and language availability constraints that do not exist when your platform is derived from a general purpose OS.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. so that means that it doesn't matter which framework i'll use? .net framework 4.5 or .net compact framework 3.5? I mean beside your arguments. Both are working on the embedded windows 8 platforms?

Comment: Windows 8 Embedded is simply a modular/configurable version of Windows 8 as used on the desktop.  If you can do it in Windows 8 Desktop, you can do it in Windows 8 Embedded, so long as you have selected all necessary optional components in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

C# is the "new" language, and easier to learn. Many firms use C++ still, so learn both, maybe start with C#.

The development tools are Visual Studio (can be downloaded for free on the Microsoft website). It uses the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework.

If you use [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network), there are a lot of tutorials and help to find there.

You can find Visual Studio 2012 on *[Visual Studio Express 2012 Products](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)*.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me which .net Framework? the full one or the compact?

Comment: I use the full framework as i develop for many things, try the compact one and see if it fits your needs. if it does not, then install the full framework, but i guess Visual Studio 2012 express meets the demands of most individuals.

Comment: if you could use my answers then please give me a +1 :)

Comment: just one more question. are there special embedded user controls for touch panels?

Comment: i must admit i dont know. as i have never used touch.

Comment: @user2314487 I don't believe there are any special user interface controls for touch, you only use or extend the existing ones.

Comment: Though if you are considering to do "real" embedded development in the future, as opposed to portable PC development in Windows 8, C/C++ is the only option.

Comment: @Lundin: Only option (or rather "options" C and C++ are nor one language)? Really?  The obvious and most ubiquitous options perhaps, but Ada and Forth are reasonably widely available and even C# (with .Net Micro) and NI LabView can be deployed on embedded systems.

Comment: @Clifford Sure... but it doesn't really make sense to pick a language for a new project, which has poor tool support and that few people know, when you can pick one with excellent tool support that everyone knows. If you start a taxi company, you _could_ put a lot of effort into searching for a car with three wheels that works just as well as the regular one with four. And you could aim to only employ people who are used to driving three-wheel cars. But why would you? What is the benefit?

Comment: @Lundin:  Tool quality or cost, market share and staff availability may be issues but clearly C and C++ are not the "only options".  Ada is in fact widely used in defence, aerospace, space and safety critical applications such as rail signalling, and in many cases is specified as a project requirement and therefore truly the "only option".